# How to get Bak file or MDF without close connection sql server?

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008, mdf

i have a database (ms 2005 server). How to get bak or mdf file BUT; it is running windows 2008 server also over 600 stuffs is using this DB. if i get .bak file or mdf. i must close connection. i dislike it. is there any useful methods or method to get BAK or MDF? this method may be a EXE or ms sql property or tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not need to drop users to make a backup. Just right click your database in SQL Server Management Studio -> Tasks -> Back Up

Even better, setup a regular backup schedule.

Here's further instructions on [backing up SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).